# Alternative to the Windows Service Manager (services.msc) which supports filtering out signed Microsoft executables?

Tags: windows, software-rec, services, windows-services

Is there a Service Manager for Windows which allows me to easily filter out all the Microsoft services with verified signatures?

I've looked at [Turbo Services Manager](http://www.turboirc.com/tsm/) but it doesn't have this feature.

Comment: Any alternative able to group services in order to enable and disable several at once?

Comment: `MSConfig` has similar feature but I'm not sure if it checks for digital signature

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) has a tab that lists installed services, and can both verify digital signatures and filter out Microsoft services.  It's not as "nice" as `services.msc`, but it will do the job.

Comment: Tip: Turn off the Microsoft filter so you can see all the services

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line (WMIC) tool](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wmic.mspx?mfr=true), using the command:

> cmd.exe wmic service

This will return you a list of installed services. If you use a pipe to a txt file you can import it on MS Excel and make all filters that you want.